# Rails Infinite Loop when redirect to finish_singup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm working on a website for a nonprofit association using rails.

And we're having a problem when the user logging in through a social network (facebook, twitter) for first time.

At the time of registration on the page through a social network, the page redirects the user to a final form (finish_signup) where the user fill it with additional data (mail, gender, date of birth) but when the user press click on **Continue**  the pages redirects the user again to the end form (finish_singup) and thus stays in an infinite loop.

This is what the console show me when the user press **Continue**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2s8s.png

When I check on the database I see that the extra information asked on the final form (finish_singup) It does not appear, only the information when the user press click on "**Sing up with twitter**

Only when I fill the data required (mail, gender, date of birth) manually from the database I can overcome the infinite loop and redirects the user to the main page.

this is what i have on home_controller.rb

```
 class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :user_has_signed_in

  def index
    logger.info request.headers['CustomHeader']
  end

  private
  def user_has_signed_in
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to main_path
    end
  end
end
```

And this is what I have on the user.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :identities
  has_many :session_ids

  TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX = 'change@me'
  TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX = /\Achange@me/

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :registerable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook,:twitter]

  validates_format_of :email, without: TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX, on: :update

  has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :affectation_votes
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes
  has_many :activity_records

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  #validates :gender, presence: true
  #validates :birthdate, presence: true
  has_attached_file :avatar
  # validates_attachment :avatar, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/bmp"] }, size: { less_than: 1.megabytes }
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :avatar

  def avatar_url
    omniauth_image || (avatar.url =~ /missing/ ? nil : avatar.url)
  end

  def report_count
    reports.count
  end

  def comment_count
    comments.count
  end

  def level
    number_of_reports = reports.count
    if number_of_reports >= 60
      return 9
    elsif number_of_reports >= 45
      return 8
    elsif number_of_reports >= 35
      return 7
    elsif number_of_reports >= 25
      return 6
    elsif number_of_reports >= 20
      return 5
    elsif number_of_reports >= 15
      return 4
    elsif number_of_reports >= 10
      return 3
    elsif number_of_reports >= 5
      return 2
    else
      return 1
    end
  end

  def since
    created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
  end

  def get_uid_for_provider(provider)
    if identities.count > 0
      identities.find_by_provider(provider).uid
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def self.find_by_uid_for_provider(uid, provider)
    identity = Identity.where(provider: provider, uid: uid)
    if identity
      identity.user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)

    # Get the identity and user if they exist
    identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)

    # If a signed_in_resource is provided, it always overrides the existing user
    # to prevent the identity beign locked with accidentally created accounts.
    # Note that this may leave zombie accounts (with no associated identity) which
    # can be cleaned up at a later date.
    user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

    # Create the user if needed
    if user.nil?

      # Get the existing user by email if the provider gives us a verified email.
      # If no verified email was provided we assign a temporary email and ask the 
      # user to verify it on the next step via UsersController.finish_signup
      email_is_verfied = auth.info.email && (auth.info.verified || auth.info.verified_email)
      email = auth.info.email if email_is_verfied
      user = User.where( email: email ).first if email

      # Create the user if it is a new registration
      if user.nil?
          # logger.info auth
          user = User.new(
            name: auth.extra.raw_info.name,
            email: email ? email : "#{TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX}-#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}.com",
            password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
            omniauth_image: auth.info.image
          )
          user.skip_confirmation!
          user.save!
        end
      end

      # Associate the identity with the user if needed
      if identity.user != user
        identity.user = user
        identity.save!
      end
      user
    end

    def email_verified?
      self.email && self.email !~ TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX
    end
```

This is the repo page of the server if you want take a look

https://github.com/denialtorres/YoCDDN/

I would really appreciate if I can help in this. greetings :)

Comment: When you submit the `finish_signup` form did you look in console that if there is `unpermitted parameters: username`? In short is the username stored in db when you submit the form?

Comment: Hi!! thanks for your help. I dont get any `unpermitted  parameters: username` I only get `Filter chain halted as :check_complete_user_data rendered or redirected` then the page reload on `finish_signup` again. The username and the mail is never stored on the db even when I put them on the form. This is how it looks the db [link] http://i.imgur.com/AonrjZh.png [link]  On the console I only see GET methods but never a PATCH or PUT when I press **Continue**

Comment: See the answer and try that should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `users_controller` you have:

```
def user_params
      accessible = [ :name, :email ] # extend with your own params
      accessible << [ :password, :password_confirmation ] unless params[:user][:password].blank?
      params.require(:user).permit(accessible)
end
```

which doesn't permit `username` to be saved. So in the `before_filter`:

```
def check_complete_user_data
    unless params['action'] =~ /finish_signup/
      if user_signed_in?
        if current_user.username.nil?
          redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}/finish_signup"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

you have checked that if username if nil then redirect to the `finish_signup` path. So just permit the `username` the issue will be resolved. Like this:

```
def user_params
      accessible = [ :name, :email, :username ] # extend with your own params
      accessible << [ :password, :password_confirmation ] unless params[:user][:password].blank?
      params.require(:user).permit(accessible)
end
```

And in the image as you are showing nothing is being stored this is because you are not permitting any attribute in the strong parameters.

And as you checking for a patch request and not sending one so make it as:

```
<%= form_for(current_user, :as => 'user', :url => finish_signup_path(current_user), :method => :patch, :html => { role: 'form', onsubmit: 'return validateTerms()', class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
```

So this will send a `patch` request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much !!

that was the problem. Now I can fill the final form and go straight to the main screen. And now I could even add a button to make a sing in/up via google. Thank you again! I was stuck with this problem for a whole week :P. regards